# Struts getting values from checkbox

Tags: java, jsp, struts, struts-1

I am having a struts app with a jsp page that populates check boxes from collection as below

**UserDetails.java**

```
public class UserDetails extends ActionForm 
{
   private Collection userSkills;   
   .
   //Getters and Setters for userSkills      
   .
   .
   .
   public void reset(ActionMapping mapping, HttpServletRequest request)
   {
    userSkills = new ArrayList();
    userSkills.add(new LabelValueBean("java", "Java"));
    userSkills.add(new LabelValueBean("mysql", "MySQL"));
    userSkills.add(new LabelValueBean("php", "PHP"));
    userSkills.add(new LabelValueBean("css", "CSS"));
    userSkills.add(new LabelValueBean("html", "Html"));
   }

}
```

I am Populating the JSP page with the values from collection as Below

**RegisterUser.jsp**

```
<logic:iterate property="userSkills" id="userDet" name="User">
   <html:checkbox property="label" name="userDet" indexed="true">
      <bean:write property="label" name="userDet"></bean:write>
    </html:checkbox>
</logic:iterate>
```

The Output is as below

[image]

Now while submitting the form I want the values from the Checked Check box alone.I don't want to write 5 separate lines for getting values from each check box. How to do this

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2):

Struts has a tag that fit your needs : multibox, you can see these links :

- http://struts.apache.org/release/1.2.x/userGuide/struts-html.html#multibox
- http://www.jguru.com/faq/view.jsp?EID=925277

And convert your collection to an array

Answer (score 1):

### In Userdetails.java

```
    public class UserDetails extends ActionForm { 
    private String[] userSkills;
   //setter and getter for userSkills
}
```

### In RegisterUser.jsp

```
<html:multibox property="userSkills" value="java"/> java
<html:multibox property="userSkills" value="mysql"/> mysql
<html:multibox property="userSkills" value="php"/> php
```

Try to use this